# multiprocessing in django with db queires in each process

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have around 30k items in db where each one must be processed and dumped out into a file.

```
def reset_database_connection():
    from django import db
    db.close_old_connections()

all_ids = [q_id for q_id in MyModel.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)]

# chunk the huge list into 5 parts
chunked_all_ids = [all_ids[i::5] for i in xrange(5)]

for ids in chunked_all_ids:
    p = Process(target=my_script, args=(ids, ids[0]))

    # close parent process db connection, so each new process creates its own one
    reset_database_connection()
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

in `my_script` I will query the db, get some infos and write into a file. inside my_script, I will reset db connections again where queries happen for longer time

When I run the code, I am getting starting from the Process-2 the error

```
OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

what am I doing wrong here? how can I create 5 processes where each process can handle 6k items on its own without losing db connection?

I am using python2 and django 1.8

Comment: You can also read data from db in chunks http://www.poeschko.com/2012/02/memory-efficient-django-queries/ . It seems that when you reset the connection then its not available for process 2. It should work if each process has its own db connection and closing db connection of one process should not affect to other process.

Comment: @ManinderSingh yes you are right, but I am already doing it this way. but your second point is really interesting.. I am investigating more..

Comment: Please simply close all db connection **db.connections.close_all()** just before launching processes, each process recreate connection itself when it will need one.

Comment: @ManinderSingh that worked! thank you so much